# Clion or cmake does not see environment variable

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, clion, root-framework

I'm using CLion IDE, Cmake and trying to write *Hello world* using CERN ROOT library.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

`message(STATUS $ENV{ROOTSYS})`

**~/.bashrc**:

`export ROOTSYS="$HOME/tools/root-build/"`

During build in CLion `$ENV{ROOTSYS}` is empty by some reason. But `$ENV{PATH}` returns correct `$PATH`.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 18):

Variables from .bashrc **aren't** passed.

Go to File -> Settings -> **Build,Execution,Deployment**

### For Clion 2017.2+

[image]
[image]

---

### For old Clion

[image]

Click Pass system and...

[image]

---

If you want to read environment variable in C++ runtime e.g. using [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) then 
it won't work as we added environment variable for **CMAKE** not for runtime.

You can add such variable:
[image]

And then in your code:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path getRootConfigPath()
{
    // std::getenv can return nullptr and this is why we CAN'T assign it directly to std::string
    const char* path = std::getenv("TEST_CONFIG_DIR");
    gcpp::exception::fail_if_true(
        path == nullptr, WHERE_IN_FILE, "No such environment variable: ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR}");

    gcpp::exception::fail_if_true(std::string_view{path}.empty(),
                                  WHERE_IN_FILE,
                                  "Missing ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR} environment variable");

    const std::filesystem::path testConfigDir{path};
    gcpp::exception::fail_if_false(std::filesystem::exists(testConfigDir) &&
                                       std::filesystem::is_directory(testConfigDir),
                                   WHERE_IN_FILE,
                                   "Invalid ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR} dir:" + testConfigDir.string());
    return testConfigDir;
}
```

Source of [gcpp::exception::fail_if_true](https://github.com/gelldur/gcpp/blob/master/src/gcpp/exception/fail.hpp)

---

Other way to do this in more friendly way when running unit tests is add this variable to template.

So whenever you click:
[image]

Such variable will be there already.

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can update this to match the 2017.2 version of CLion? It doesn't look anything like these screen shots.

Comment: Is it possible to specify RC file for a shell that's used to run CMake? There are cases when environment variables are not so good - for example, I install Conan (package manager) to ./local and then add this directory to the PATH (via .bashrc), but I still cannot run Conan from the CMake.

Answer (score 13):

From CLion developers [FAQ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/):

> Q: How to pass environment variables and parameters to CMake in CLion?
>
> A: The best way is to use Preferences/Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake dialog.

As for `.bashrc` file, it is only used by *bash*. CLion doesn't need to use *bash* for run configuration process.

Comment: Clion will pick up environment variables set in the `/etc/environment` file.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 17.04, you can set a permanent environment variable by modifying

```
    /etc/enviornment
```

[I assume you can do this in other versions of Linux, but I provide the version of the system that I am using.]

For example, I am compiling test cases that assume that ${GOOGLE_MOCK} has been set.  I added the following to my `/etc/environment` file, and now I don't have to rewrite all of my CMakeLists.txt files:

```
    GOOGLE_MOCK=/usr/local/src/googletest/googlemock
    GOOGLE_TEST_HOME=/usr/local/src/googletest/googletest
```

Clion just became much more useable.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is the `.gdbinit`. Clion on Linux will invoke the gdb, which will read in the `.gdbinit`. I happen to have `set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH xxx` in my `.gdbinit` file, which will override whatever you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from shell, whether through direct `export` or through `.bashrc`, or from CLion environment variable panel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Source your variables in .profile not .bashrc