# C++ Program through CLion cannot find environment variable

Tags: c++, cmake, environment-variables, clion

I am trying to write a C++ program in CLion and use one self-defined environment variable. The OS is *Ubuntu 16.04*

Say the environment variable is the $test.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

    std::cout<<getenv("PATH");
    std::cout<<getenv("test");
}
```

I have set the environment variable in the setting->build...->CMAKE->Environment
[environment variable set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5qYY.png)

I am able to print it when build through CMAKE.

```
message($ENV{test}) 

this is test
```

But whenbuild and run the compiled code above, only $PATH was print out. It seems the program cannot find the $test variable.

Anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Typically IDEs allow separate environments for building and running your program. Set environment variable in your "Run configuration", not in CMake options.

Comment: @yeputons thanks! It works after set the environment variable in "run configuration"

Comment: Related question about CMake environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874446/1052261

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know CLion, but it sure looks like you set the environment variable for use in CMake only. When you run your program, it's simply not set.

Comment: yes! just like @yeputons said, after set the environment variable in the run configuration, it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and below steps resolved my issue.
Set your variables in

> Run->Edit Configurations, Application/Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read environment variable in C++ runtime e.g. using [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

You can add such variable in "Run Configurations" (IMPORTANT **not** CMake environment variables)
[image]

And then in your code:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path getRootConfigPath()
{
    // std::getenv can return nullptr and this is why we CAN'T assign it directly to std::string
    const char* path = std::getenv("TEST_CONFIG_DIR");
    gcpp::exception::fail_if_true(
        path == nullptr, WHERE_IN_FILE, "No such environment variable: ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR}");

    gcpp::exception::fail_if_true(std::string_view{path}.empty(),
                                  WHERE_IN_FILE,
                                  "Missing ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR} environment variable");

    const std::filesystem::path testConfigDir{path};
    gcpp::exception::fail_if_false(std::filesystem::exists(testConfigDir) &&
                                       std::filesystem::is_directory(testConfigDir),
                                   WHERE_IN_FILE,
                                   "Invalid ${TEST_CONFIG_DIR} dir:" + testConfigDir.string());
    return testConfigDir;
}
```

Source of [gcpp::exception::fail_if_true](https://github.com/gelldur/gcpp/blob/master/src/gcpp/exception/fail.hpp)

---

Other way to do this in more friendly way when running unit tests is add this variable to template.

So whenever you click:
[image]

Such variable will be there already.

[image]