# Resolve Python Modules of a Catkin Workspace in CLion

Tags: python, cmake, clion, catkin

I have a catkin workspace that consists of both C++ and Python packages. I have problems in resolving python modules in CLion and I need help with configuring that.

I have already copied the top level `CMakeLists.txt` to my workspace source directory (`my_ws/src`). When I build by using the top level cmake, and then source `cmake-build-debug/devel/setup.zsh`, and launch python shell afterwards, everything is fine: workspace structure is resolved and i can use autocompletion. The same applies when i source `my_ws/devel_debug/setup.zsh`.

In Clion Terminal, when i enter `$ echo $PYTHONPATH` i get `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which is insufficient. It lacks the dir at which `__init__.py` files of my packages are located.

In Clion settings, under `[Build, Execution, Deployment]` window my `[Python Interpreter]` settings are set correct: project interpreter is my python virtual environment, and the path `my_ws/src/cmake-build_debug/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` is already added. I left the CMake settings as they are, because these do not allow to specify anything about `$PYTHONPATH` -- at least i couldn't figure out how!

When i run CMake in Clion, i see `my_ws/src/cmake-build-debug/devel` listed as `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX` under my `PYTHONPATH`.

P.S. I have already checked [Clion or cmake does not see environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662130/clion-or-cmake-does-not-see-environment-variable) and some other pages to get some clues, but they didn't help.