# LD_LIBRARY_PATH ignored when CLion runs built targets

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, clion, dynamic-loading

I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to some directory, in my `.bashrc`. However, when CLion runs targets it builds for a project of mine, it seems that path is ignored somehow, and shared libraries are not found:

```
/home/joeuser/src/myproj/cmake-build-debug/bin/myapp
/home/joeuser/src/myproj/cmake-build-debug/bin/myapp: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

if I run this executable from a shell session, it runs fine and locates libfoo.so.11.0 based on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

What do I do?

Notes:

- My system distribution is Devuan GNU/Linux Daedalus.
- If I invoke the program within CMake's Terminal tab - it works!
- I made sure I have an `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda` file with the appropriate path in it.

Comment: Does cmake-build use bash?  dash/sh would use .profile  Do you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @AllanWind: 1. That's what it uses in the terminal tab... 2. `.profile` doesn't get run, I just checked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clion or cmake does not see environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662130/clion-or-cmake-does-not-see-environment-variable)

Comment: @AllanWind: No, it doesn't. That question is about variables during _build_. I'm taking about _execution_.

Comment: Ok, I retracted said vote.